# String to Date mongodb using node.js and moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, momentjs

In my application i allow user to set a date using a date-picker component.

My issue is when trying to convert string date to UTC/ISO date format the conversion is not happening properly, see the below example.

**Example:**

User Selected String Date : `01/09/2015 (DD/MM/YYYY)`

While im using moment.js to convert the above date to native JS date, **See below:**

```
moment(req.body.datePicker,'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

All good till here, but when the data stored in db the date is getting reduced by 1 day. I have no idea where its getting messed up.

I have managed to create a re-producable scenario using [jsfiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/r42jg/1003/) please have a look for a better understanding.

**My assumption:**

when i see the db collection the date is getting stored with a default time: `18:30:00.00Z` [image]

this could be one of the reason why the dates are getting changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is **timezone**.

In my case 01/09/2015 gives 2015-01-08T23:00:00 which is only -1 hour since my timezone is GMT+1

Comment: But a workaround for this issue? the default 18:30:00.00Z is creating problem here. If we can set the time to 00:00:00.00Z i think the problem can be solved.

Comment: @FahidMohammad  I doubt that 18:30:00 is default time. Isn't your timezone by any chance GMT+5:30. If so then 01/09/2015 gives 2015-01-08T18:30:00 which make sense to me. So my answer is pointing out your problem and solution is quite simply. There's **no workaround needed** as it is not an issue. You just need to take timezones into account like all the others do. Have a look at this http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0):

Finally after doing some research i myself found the solution or a hack to fix this issue, it may not be the correct way of doing it but for the current scenario it worked like a charm.

**Solution:**

All i did was just created a full ISO/UTC date string hard-coding the time to zero. `moment(req.body.datePicker,'DD/MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.000').toString()+'Z'` by doing this the default time will always set to Zero and since the string is a fully qualified ISO/UTC standard format, mongoDB will not try to alter it.

**Working example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/r42jg/1004/

If any one has a better solution, the please post here so we can improvise this better.